# Can't access the wp-admin page on wordpress site after login

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-lightsail

After login to the wordpress and accessing site URL

> [www.abc.ae/wp-admin](http://www.abc.ae/wp-admin)

always throwing this

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

I had try by removing plugins, themes and htaccess. But this error is showing when I  login successfully and trying to access wp-admin.

Comment: are you try to login with admin account?

Comment: yes trying with admin account

Comment: How can i make sure my account role is admin

Comment: you can check it in your database, usermeta table

Comment: if the user role have 10 value then it will be admin

Comment: yeah the role value is 10

Comment: can you on the debug so you will get the idea

Comment: 10 does not seem a correct value for the capabilities. can you try the following. Open your wp-config.php and look for the $table_prefix and copy its value you'll need it to construct the query. `SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_prefix}usermeta m INNER JOIN {$table_prefix}users u ON u.ID = m.user_id WHERE m.meta_key = '{$table_prefix}capabilities' and u.user_login = '{your_use_name}'` the resulting query should look somthing like this `SELECT meta_value FROM JNcKI_usermeta m INNER JOIN JNcKI_users u ON u.ID = m.user_id WHERE m.meta_key = 'JNcKI_capabilities' and u.user_login = 'admin'`

Comment: the result should look like this `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}`

Comment: if you already testing I corrected the query it had a small typo

Comment: this is the value i have ```a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}```

Comment: It return me a zero rows. Looks like somethings is wrong

Comment: @JasperB please let me know how can I insert

Comment: ok looking at the message you send before it is set, correctly, `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` did you change the {$table_prefix} with the one in your wp-config.php ? and {your_use_name} with your username ?

Comment: yes @JasperB I got the values ```a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}```

Comment: Table prefix is correct in the table

Comment: @JasperB any luck ?

Comment: If you are using php my admin you can add it from there go first you have to lookup the ID of your user in the {$table_prefix}users table, then go back into the {$table_prefix}usermeta table and add a new row, fill in the following fields `user_id` = `the user id of your user`, `meta_key` = `{$table_prefix}capabilities` and `meta_value` = `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}` leave all other fields blank.